# Show waves in Modelsim with Cocotb

Tags: modelsim, cocotb

I'm getting started with cocotb.
I can run the example tests. They don't fail and cocotb terminates with success. My usual simulator is modelsim. If I start cocotb with: 
`make GUI=1 WAVES=1` I get the GUI of modelsim and can see the signals in the objects window. The only thing I did never get are the signals in the wave window. I can add them manually over the GUI, but this is too late. The test has already finished.

What is the correct way to select the waves I want to see?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `SCRIPT_FILE` makefile variable to point to a modelsim `wave.do` file, which you should be able to produce from the GUI.